# Get all selected JList items - JFrame Form Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jlist

I need to get all selected items from JList and remove those items from list. Here is the incomplete code:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    List selFromList = this.jList1.getSelectedValuesList();//This line gives me error
}
```

Please help.

Comment: What's the error? Which `List` are you importing? There's more than one. You need `java.util.List`

Comment: `This line gives me error`  1) Always copy/paste error & exception output. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: It's worth reading [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get all selected items and remove from list as below:

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
this.jList1.setModel(model);

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//on clicking remove button  
    java.util.List selFromList = this.jList1.getSelectedValuesList();
    for(int i=0;i<selFromList.size();i++){
        selectedVal = selFromList.get(i).toString();
        model.removeElement(selectedVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use toString when you use get, you should API ply be able to feed the result of the get call directly to the removeElement call